# Call custom filter angularjs from controller

Tags: angularjs, filter

My scenario is seemingly simple, but I have tried numerous approaches without success.
I need to call a filter on my controlller, this filter is for a mask, turn this 348845697990 into it 348.8456.979-90. Well, follow my codes below:
1: My module:

```
angular.module('webclientody', []);

angular.module('webclientody').filter('cpf', function () {
return function (input) {
        var str = input + '';
        if (str.length <= 11) {
            str = str.replace(/\D/g, '');
            str = str.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2");
            str = str.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2");
            str = str.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/, "$1-$2");
        }
        return str;
    };
});
```

My controller:

```
angular.module('webclientody').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, 
$http, $location, $cookies, $rootScope, apiUrl, $filter) {

    $scope.init = function () {

        var cpf = "348845697990";
        cpf = $filter("cpf")(cpf);

    };

    $scope.init();

});
```

If I cut this code and test it on a small separate project, it works. But, in my project occurs the error:

```
> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=cpfFilterProvider%20%3C-%20cpfFilter
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4458
    at Object.d [as get] (angular.js:4611)
    at angular.js:4463
    at Object.d [as get] (angular.js:4611)
    at angular.js:19531
    at b.$scope.init (LoginCtrl.js:6)
    at new <anonymous> (LoginCtrl.js:10)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4665)
    at R.instance (angular.js:10115)
```

I've tried several approaches, but it always returns this error. Anyone have any suggestions?

Tks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You missed out to inject `ngCookies` module. And check `apiUrl` also included or not.

```
  angular.module('webclientody', ['ngCookies']);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: Buddy, no error occurs. It simply does not apply the filter. I ended up resolving without using a filter. Thanks for the answers !

Answer (score 0):

try injecting `cpf` filter to your controller:

```
angular.module('webclientody')
       .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, $cookies, $rootScope, apiUrl, cpf) {}
```

and use it as below:

```
var testData = "348845697990";
cpf(testData);
```

Comment: filter was created by angular.module('webclientody') it'self. So we don't need to inject cpf.

Comment: @ManikandanVelayutham inject `$filter` will basically inject all filters including built-in filters and custom filters. and the way I provided will only inject the target filter. some time we will need the second way.